# Why did Queen Amidala decline a Senate investigation of her accusations against the Trade Federation?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, padme

When Queen Amidala addressed the Senate regarding the Trade Federation blockade of Naboo, she was asked if she would allow a Senate committee to investigate her claims. However, she declined and instead asked for a vote of "no confidence" in Chancellor Valorum.

Why didn't she accept the offer to send a committee? The committee would have seen what was happening.

---

Note: the idea for this question came from http://www.moviemistakes.com/member354/title976

Comment: Because it would take too long. "***I was not elected to watch my people suffer and die while you discuss this invasion in a committee!***"

Comment: Why did Amidala cross the road? To get to the light side.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### She did not want to delay when the matter was so urgent

From the [script* for *The Phantom Menace*](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html):

> AMIDALA : (angrily) **I will not defer**...I have come before you to
> resolve this attack on our sovereignty now. **I was not elected to watch
> my people suffer and die while you discuss this invasion** in a
> committee. If this body is not capable of action, I suggest new
> leadership is needed. I move for a "vote of no confidence"...in
> Chancellor Valorum's leadership.
>
> VALORUM : What?...No!

As to why she asked for a vote of no confidence, the proximal cause was Valorum's poor handling of the Naboo crisis. The actual cause, of course, was Palpatine's manipulation, with the ultimate goal of making himself Emperor.

<sub>*Script not final version.</sub>

Comment: Yes, because voting for new leadership is *sooooooooooooo* much faster than traveling to a planet at FTL speeds.

Comment: @Ellesedil: the problem with traveling to Naboo isn't the traveling, it's the getting ready. Imagine a group of teenagers deciding what to do that evening, and raise it to the third power. As Amidala said, she doesn't have time to wait for the Senate to discuss the matter in committee.

Comment: @Ellesedil Imagine them deciding who is on the committee. Imagine the committee voting on whether to go. Imagine whoever goes writing a report. Imagine the committee reading the report. Imagine the committee debating the report. Imagine the committee voting on a recommendation. Imagine the committee writing a new report including their findings and recommendation. Imagine this report being distributed to the rest of the Senate. Imagine the Senate reviewing it and finally voting to do nothing. A bureaucracy's inability to act swiftly is a point that dictators can leverage to come to power.

Comment: @Ellesedil: you are mistaking “investigations” for “travelling there and looking what’s going on”. If the Senate will start “investigations”, it means “building a committee which will send orders to executives to create exposés which will eventually lead to the executives delegating the work to someone who *might* travel to the planet, though it’s more likely that they will search for witnesses to interrogate them instead, which will lead to ask Amidala and the two Jedi, which are the only known witnesses”. Maybe they will also invite the Trade Federation to explain their point of view, etc.

Answer (score 25):

First off, **Valorum wasn't sending any help, he was only sending people to check if she was telling the truth.**

> VALORUM: Will you defer your motion
>   to allow a commission
>   to explore the validity
>   of your accusations?

Palpatine had convinced her that Vallorum was incapable of acting in a timely manner to help them, saying bureaucracy and corruption limited the ability to act effectively and swiftly.

> PALPATINE: There is no civility,
>   only politics.
>   The Republic
>   is not what it once was.
>   The senate is full of greedy,
>   squabbling delegates.
>   There is no interest
>   in the common good.
>   I must be frank, Your Majesty.
>   There is little chance the senate
>   will act on the invasion
>
> AMIDALA: Chancellor Valorum
>   seems to think there is hope.
>
> PALPATINE: If I may say so, Your Majesty...
>   the chancellor
>   has little real power.
>   He is mired by baseless
>   accusations of corruption.
>   - The bureaucrats are in charge now.
>
> AMIDALA: What options have we?
>
> PALPATINE: Our best choice would be
>   to push for the election...
>   of a stronger
>   supreme chancellor...
>   one who could control
>   the bureaucrats...
>   and give us justice.
>   You could call for a vote of
>   no confdence in Chancellor Valorum.
>
> AMIDALA: He has been
>   our strongest supporter.
>
> PALPATINE: Our only other choice would be
>   to submit a plea to the courts.
>
> AMIDALA: The courts take even longer
>   to decide things than the senate.
>   Our people are dying, Senator.
>   We must do something quickly
>   to stop the Federation.

So, when she saw Valorum was only going to send people to *check* if there was a problem, *rather than take real action to **help** Naboo*, the Queen took this as proof Palpatine was right. She therefore felt a vote of no confidence, getting a new leader who *could/would* do something, was her only option left.

> PALPATINE: now they will elect a new chancellor, a strong chancellor. One that will not let our tragedy to continue.

As it turns out, this all was part of his plan to

> become chancellor and rule the galaxy.

---

<sub>All quotes from the film's [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=star-wars-episode-i-the-phantom-menace)</sub>

Comment: What? Palpatine became the Emperor? Next you're going to tell me that Vader is Luke's father or something.

Comment: @RogueJedi Spoiler alert!

Comment: @RogueJedi I agree - RedCaio must have watched a different movie to the rest of us, because the Emperor is some guy called Sidious, not Palpantine!  It's like saying Chewie and Han aren't brothers! 

Comment: Chewie and Han are brothers! Noooo!!!

Comment: Which ultimately means that Order 66, the Younglings, the destruction of Alderaan, basically everything bad that happened from Episode II onward, can be squarely blamed on Amidala stupidly allowing Palpatine to take control of the Senate.  This is why you don't let 14 year-olds become queens of entire planets.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Palpatine wouldn't have been able to do a tenth of the stuff he did if JarJar hadn't convinced the senate to grant him emergency powers...

Comment: Don't let 14 year olds or frog-people become involved in politics full stop. Oh, and if you see a little kid destroy millions of credits worth of droid control ship, give him a clip round the ear instead of training him to be a Jedi.

Comment: @PaulL Darth Jar Jar you mean?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have to disagree with you. There were a *lot* of other factors not really under her control, from manipulating Anakin, to giving the command to execute Order 66, to the Trade Federation being manipulated, to the commissioning of the Death Star. While the vote of no confidence was certainly a bad thing, you can't ignore the responsibility of the people who *actually committed the atrocities*, and you can only place so much blame on someone trying to stop a literal, deadly military invasion of her home world.

Comment: Oh, wow, aim for the low-hanging fruit and blame the frog. How about blame the person who let the frog be in charge? Or barring that, blame the guy looking for a weak link to break, (our good buddy palp.)